# Caesar's wife must be above suspicion

Tags: meaning, proverbs

What is the interpretation of the following proverb?

> Caesar's wife must be above suspicion.

Does it mean that people associated with public figures must act cautiously to avoid suspicion of wrongdoing, or **everyone** must act in that manner?

See [WordReference](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/caesars-wife-must-be-above-suspicion.3095513/) for discussion. I'm wondering what the mainstream view is.

Comment: If you haven't heard the proverb used, you are not in a position to answer the question.

Comment: When you write "anyone" did you mean "everyone" or *no one* e.g Everyone/No one  must behave well.  The pronoun "anyone" is used in questions, negatives (Did anyone see what happened? /He didn't see any one) or in affirmative sentences when referring to any individual (learning Spanish is easy, anyone can do it).

Comment: @Mari-LouA  Post edited as per your information

Answer (score 2):

It's not so much a proverb as a quotation referring to a real incident. Julius Caesar divorced his second wife [Pompeia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeia_(wife_of_Caesar)) after she had been associated with a scandal, even though he was personally convinced of her innocence, to avoid damage to his own reputation.

Comment: I'm asking about its non-literal meaning, i.e., how it is used beyond the original context.

Comment: Well, Wiktionary interprets it as  _Those in positions of authority should avoid even the implication of impropriety._ I see that as the 'official' meaning, but others (like Mohsen) may interpret it in different ways.

Comment: Some sources say it's those associated with people in positions of authority that should avoid the suspicion.

Answer (score -3):

If someone is thought to be above suspicion, it means that "no one" would ever suspect that they have done anything wrong—or are even capable of it. The phrase is typically applied to people who are thought to have a spotless reputation.

The key word in the above definition is "no one". It means no one should ever dare to suspect that Caesar's wife has done anything wrong no matter how she acts. It creates some kind of immunity for Ceasar's wife, so that she can potentially commit crimes without ever being suspected of that crime.

Comment: Please cite your source (where you quote the proverb's definition) and add a link also.